# How to invoke a wcf service in a custom server control class?

Tags: wcf, client, servercontrol

I am developing an Custom Server Control (Ex: a TextBox) which would help a deveoper to bind a control directly to the service layer.

My Requirement.

1. The text box will have the Attributes like (**Service URL, Method, Parameter** under my new category called **Service Properties**)
2. In URL, I can pass the service host path.

is there any way where we can populate the methods available in the service on the Method Attribute as a dropdown (Like Enum) automatically.

then the developer can choose the right parameter based on the selected method.

I know it's very hard, but is there any way to overcome this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If the web service is a SOAP service then you can get the wsdl into a XDocument object or XmlDocument and then read the wsdl:operation elements within wsdl:portType element to get all the operations available.

NOTE: This is possible only if the wsdl is exposed by the service provider.

Sample wsdl with few operations as shown:

```
<wsdl:portType name="ISampleService">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetData">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISampleService/GetData" message="tns:ISampleService_GetData_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISampleService/GetDataResponse" message="tns:ISampleService_GetData_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetEmail">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISampleService/GetEmail" message="tns:ISampleService_GetEmail_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISampleService/GetEmailResponse" message="tns:ISampleService_GetEmail_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetPersonCount">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISampleService/GetPersonCount" message="tns:ISampleService_GetPersonCount_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISampleService/GetPersonCountResponse" message="tns:ISampleService_GetPersonCount_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
```

The above section from a service exposes 3 methods:

1. GetData
2. GetEmail
3. GetPersonCount

Comment: but in my case, wsdl is not exposed... :(